# Migrate multiple certificate signing to single certificate

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-app-signing

My org android app is signed with 2 Keystore files. So while doing app signing on Play Store, I am getting the following message

```
Your app cannot be enrolled into App Signing because of the following reasons:
We do not support enrolling apps signed with multiple keys
```

So, wants to know if there is any way to move from 2 certificate signings to 1 certificate keeping the same app in Play Store

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible today.

For app updates to work, the Android framework requires that the app be signed by the same certificates, so it is not possible to change the certificates. The only option would be to create a new app (i.e. new package name).

Android has introduced key rotation, which could possibly help with this situation, but it is unfortunately not supported by Play to this day.

Comment: Android P key rotation will not help here